# Java StringBuffer works fine, reverse() adds linebreaks

Tags: java, stream, buffer, stringbuffer

In the following code, case 2 prints the text file in normal order, it works fine. But in case 3, the exact same thing, but using the method .reverse(), it adds line breaks out of nowhere. (I know I can cut out a lot of repetition, I'm trying to get it working first.)

Example:

> Marcus
> 1244

looks like

> 4421
>
> scuraM

using \r or \n instead of line.separator gives me the same exact thing. taking it away, of course, gives me one smashed together line.

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class H5 {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner stdin2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String filePath = null;
    int selection;
    boolean repeat = true;
    FileInputStream f = null;
    
    do {  
        System.out.println("\n0 - Exit\n1 - Select file\n2 - Display\n3 - Reverse\nSelect option: ");
        selection = stdin.nextInt();
        switch (selection) {
        case 0:  System.out.println("\nThank you. Goodbye.");
                 repeat = false;
                 break;
        case 1:  System.out.println("\nFile path: ");
                 filePath = stdin2.nextLine();
                 
                 try {f = new FileInputStream(filePath);}
                 catch (Exception d) { System.out.println(d);}
                 
                 break;
        case 2:  try {
                    f = new FileInputStream(filePath);
                    DataInputStream d = new DataInputStream(f);
                    BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(d));
                    StringBuffer strbuf = new StringBuffer(200000);

                    String strLine;
                    while ((strLine = b.readLine()) != null) {
                         strbuf.append(strLine).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                     }
                    System.out.println(strbuf);
                 }
                 catch(NullPointerException npe) {
                    System.out.println("\nPlease select a file first.");
                 }
                 catch(Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                 }
                 break;
       case 3:  try {
                    f = new FileInputStream(filePath);
                    DataInputStream d = new DataInputStream(f);
                    BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(d));
                    StringBuffer strbuf = new StringBuffer(200000);

                    String strLine;
                    while ((strLine = b.readLine()) != null) {
                         strbuf.append(strLine).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                     }
                    strbuf.reverse();
                    System.out.println(strbuf);
                 }
                 catch(Exception k) {
                     System.out.println(k);
                 }
                 break;
        default: System.out.println("\nInvalid input. Please select from the following: ");
                 break;
        }
    } while(repeat);
}
}
```

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer when you can use StringBuilder.

Comment: Check the actual characters in the string.  You may discover that there are two line end characters at the end of line 1, and when you reverse them it does something unexpected.

Comment: @PeterLawrey It's an assignment. I have no choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `\r\n` is a new line, but `\n\r` is two new lines.

Comment: I tried strbuf.append(strLine).append("\b\b").append(System.getProperty("line.separator")); to see if I could delete the carriage return before new lining, but it did not work.

Comment: You can't add character to delete characters. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to get it to write the exact same thing in reverse.

Comment: Try using a single character newline of `\n` which is the same forward and backward. You can turn this into `\r\n` after reversing if you need too.

Comment: I had tried that after your first comment and thought it didn't work, but I just discovered I had been running my program without hitting Save in NetBeans between runs... embarrassing, thanks for your help.